# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax from generated script (MySQL workbench)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bm_database`.`GROUP` ( 
   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
   `problem_id` INT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   INDEX `fk_GROUP_PROBLEM1_idx` (`problem_id` ASC),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_GROUP_PROBLEM1`
      FOREIGN KEY (`problem_id`)
      REFERENCES `bm_database`.`PROBLEM` (`id`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is a generated script from MySQL workbench. All the other tables looks like this, but only this one gives the 1064 Error. I can't use `SELECT * FROM GROUP,` or `DESC GROUP;`.

*ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP' at line 1*

Comment: `GROUP` is a keyword, you should use a different name.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!

Comment: If the keyword is quoted it can be used as normal identifier. I suspect there is a problem in MySQL Workbench which generates SQL code without properly quoting the table name. You should file a bug report (http:://bugs.mysql.com) to have this fixed.